# xarray dataset.sel with args

Tags: python, python-xarray

How should the dictionary be created for xarray.dataset.sel to support
args.

xarray.dataset.sel(**args.dim**=slice(**args.since**, None)

```
dataset = xr.open_dataset(args.input_file)
variable = dataset[args.variable]
variable = variable.sel(time=slice("2018", None))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically build arguments to Python functions using `*args` and `**kwargs` syntax, e.g.,

```
dataset.sel(**{args.dim: slice(args.since, None)})
```

For xarray's `.sel()` method in particular, you can also directly pass in a dictionary as the sole positional argument, e.g.,

```
dataset.sel({args.dim: slice(args.since, None)})
```